# Not able to open the ubuntu from dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I am unable to open ubuntu in dual boot mode. The following message comes after the ubuntu screen shows up. What is the error and how do I resolve it?[image]

Comment: After this screen can you open a console using `Ctrl - Alt - F2` ?

Comment: Yes, I can open the console and access the directories.

Comment: Do a ping check by typing - `ping www.google.com`

Comment: I tried doing that but it is unable to find the host.

Comment: What does `Ctrl - Alt - F7` do?

Comment: It does nothing, however I am able to switch from one terminal to other by using other fn keys. Should I be using the fn key before Alt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44886/discussion-between-raphael-and-vibhuti-bhushan-jha).